# Cannot export gpx and kml files, laravel

Tags: xml, laravel, export, kml, formatter

I have a problem with exporting kml and gpx files using laravel controller: for json export I use function

```
 public function mapExportJSON(Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();

    $http = $client->post(
        'https://myurl' , 
        [   
            'body' => json_encode(array('points' => $request->points)),
            'headers' => [
                'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
                'Content-type' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]
    );

    $result = $http->getBody()->getContents();

    return response($result)
        ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=route.json');
}
```

I use formatter for xml, but it doesn't work :(

```
    public function mapExportKML(Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();

    $http = $client->post(
        'https://myurl' , 
        [   
            'body' => json_encode(array('points' => $request->points)),
            'headers' => [
                'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
                'Content-type' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]
    );

    $result = $http->getBody();

    $formatter = Formatter::make($result, Formatter::JSON);
    $xml  = $formatter->toXml();

    return response($xml)
        ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=route.kml')
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

}
```

Сan anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the incorrect Formatter try the below

```
  $formatter = Formatter::make($result, Formatter::XML);
  $xml  = $formatter->toXml();
```